# Core Data Model Cascade Delete and Parent Entity

Tags: core-data

I have a question about the Core Data Model and the Cascade Delete Rule.

My Core Data Model is this one:

[image: Core Data Model]

As you can see the User Entity has a "To Many" Relationship with the Orders Entity.
Also the Orders Entity has a parent entity called Cuisines, as each Order needs to be from a list of available Cuisines.

The User To Orders Relationship delete Rule is Cascade (the inverse is nullify) as I want all orders to be deleted if the user object is deleted.

**My question is what happens with the Cuisines Entity if I delete the User?**

The Cuisines should be available for all orders placed for other Users as well, so it must persist. Will it be also deleted?

If yes, how should I create my model and set the delete rules to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying `Cuisines` as the parent entity for `Orders` means that each `Orders` object *is* a `Cuisine` - albeit a specific "type" of `Cuisine`.  Each `Order` has three attributes: `numOfOrders`, `rating` and `name`.  When you delete an `Order` (albeit through a cascade rule), you are deleting one object with all three attributes - there isn't a separate `Cuisines` object to be deleted.

But you want each order to be *from* a list of available cuisines.  So replace the parent/subentity link between `Orders` and `Cuisines` with a relationship.  Each `Cuisine` can be related to several different `Orders`, so the relationship would be to-many.  Conversely, each `Order` relates to only one `Cuisine`, so the inverse relationship will be to-one.  When you delete an `Order`, you want the related `Cuisines` to remain (for use in other `Orders`) so the delete rule would be "nullify".

Comment: Thank you! That cleared it. I was thinking of doing what you suggested, just wanted to be sure it's the correct  approach.